# Is it safe to execute user entered expressions as IronPython

Tags: asp.net, security, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

I'm working on a large ASP.NET software product. We'd like to allow users to enter expressions rather than constants for certain fields. Typically something like:

```
(Price * 1.175) + 25
```

The obvious solution seems to be to embed IronPython, create a Scope, pass in the "Price" (and other) variables and then execute the above as IronPython code.

However, there would be nothing stopping users from entering:

```
1 / 0
```

or

```
def func1():
    func1()
func1()
```

or

```
import System.IO
File.Delete(....)
```

But if I catch all exceptions and run the IronPython code in an Application Domain with the Internet permission set, am I safe?

Answer (score 4):

You answer your own question by noting that there is nothing to stop the user from entering valid code. Never trust user input. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation I opted for server side JScript. To add another layer of protection I am wrapping the expression in a function and then execute the function:

```
function generated123(p1, p2, p3) {
     return
     // user code goes here
     ;
}
```

This way the user cannot force importing anything dangerous. Also server side JScript is compiled which is good for perforamnce

Comment: Just a thought, if the user enters "0;} /*evil code here*/ function dummyFunc () { return 0" Couldn't they then get you to run their evil code?

Comment: Nope. The script itself is not executed. My code only calls the generated123 function